# Data on Android/iPhone apps by user?

Tags: data-request, linked-data

I am trying to get my hands on data about app usage (iPhone and Android) by user. The users would be anonymised I assume, but I would need to link them to the range of apps they use or have installed on their phone. Is this data available or is it only available at an aggregated level?

Comment: I am gonna put on my tinfoil hat and hope that this type of data doesn't exist at all.

Comment: It doesn't look like it does (or at least not publicly available), I've continued searching and still haven't found anything.

Comment: It is commercially exploitable data mainly available to app store providers. So naturally, they would not give it away for free. If you present a valid (whatever that means) use case, you might be able to convince the free [F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/about/) contributors to open up anonyomized app usage statistics, in case they collect that at all. However, that dataset of course would exclude most popular commercial apps.

Comment: [CarrierIQ](http://www.carrieriq.com/application-analytics) has this kind of data, as do several other for-profit companies such as [comScore](http://www.comscore.com/Products/Audience_Analytics/Mobile_Metrix). But the data isn't free - nor cheap.

Comment: I'm also looking for something like this.  The other day I looked at my iPhone's app store and saw a section called "popular apps near you"....and it listed them...and they seemed quite accurate heh.  Would love to get that type of data somehow....i wonder if Apple calculated it on the fly/daily or just summarized stats into a big location....hmmm.....

Answer (score 1):

authors of the BAM application for android may have some data you are asking for.
It can recommend apps based on other users that have the same set installed.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bestappsmarket.android.bestapps&hl=en

E.g., blind users if they connect - they would recommend this way apps to each other.